# Rectifying reversible polarity battery with minimal power loss

Tags: power-supply, low-power, rectifier, battery-operated, reverse-polarity

I'd like to build a battery-powered DC power supply that will accept a single-cell battery in either polarity (i.e. it doesn't matter which way you put the battery in). I'm thinking of using the circuit below to rectify the voltage.

Are there any gotchas? Is there a better design for my constraints (listed below)?

[image: Reversible polarity circuit]

You'll notice that `Q1` and `Q2` are N-channel MOSFETs. `Q3` and `Q4` are P-channel. Let's assume they all support positive and negative gate voltages of more than the battery voltage.

The resistor labeled `LOAD` stands in the place of the rest of the power supply and everything powered by it.

My design constraints for the rectifier include:

- Very low power loss (less than 1uA quiescent current; less than 1Ohm resistance)
- Support small loads (average of 130uA, peak 20mA, minimum 5uA)
- Support single cell Li-ion (3.7 - 4.2V)
- Support battery in both polarities

Perhaps importantly, I won't be supporting the case where the battery is inserted one way and then quickly inserted the other way. In other words, I don't need to rectify square waves. For that matter I don't need to rectify AC of any kind.

Comment: You will introduce leakage currents on par with your minimum current usuage I think with any sort of configuration like this...

Comment: @MattThomas How do you define quiescent currents?

Comment: Now also draw in the **diode** that every MOSFET has between Drain and Source. Does this circuit still work?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie If you asking a rethorical question with the answer 'no', would you please explain? I can't see the problem in the forward biased diodes and like to know what I'm missing.

Comment: @Huisman I'm calling quiescent current the sum of all currents passing through the battery and not through the `LOAD`

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yes, it still works. In fact this circuit would just be a full wave bridge rectifier if the FETs' gates were disconnected and only the body diodes were considered. But driving the FETs reduces voltage drop, giving current a low impedance path other than through the body diodes

Comment: @Huisman My intention was not to suggest that the body diodes would prevent the circuit from working. I just mentioned them so that they're taken into account (not forgotten). The fact that the diodes would form a bridge rectifier is a good point,

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, mosfets have leakage currents that might be in the same range as your minimum current requirements. The blocking mosfets have a Drain-to-Source Leakage Current and the conducting mosfets will have a Gate-to-Source Leakage Current.

If these issues can be tackled, then your suggested circuit will work nicely. Therefore:
**search internet for (ultra) low leakage mosfets.**

I found that way the nice [CSD23381F4](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd23381f4.pdf) 12V P-Channel FemtoFET <sup>TM</sup> MOSFET.

It has:

- really less than 100 nA I<sub>DSS</sub> (because V<sub>DS</sub> is max -4.2 V instead of -9.6 V)
- really less than 50 nA I<sub>GSS</sub> (because V<sub>GS</sub> is max -4.2 V instead of -8 V)
- less than 300 mΩ ON resistance (because V<sub>GS</sub> < -2.5V and I<sub>DS</sub> is max -0.020 A)
- Support single cell Li-ion (3.7 - 4.2V) because of its low V<sub>GS</sub> and a V<sub>DS</sub> of -12 V.
- costs only 0.05 / 1ku

[image]

**DISCLAIMER**
I don't know if you want to make a PCB or even a breadboard (please don't do the latter), and were planning hand soldering: then this package might be a problem.
This answer is more to point out what keywords to search on and what parameters to consider. It's also the reason only a PMOS is suggested.

Comment: Will I also need to consider Gate-to-Source leakage currents for the blocking MOSFETs? Those will also have a voltage applied to their gates (negative for the N-channel, positive for the P-channel)

Comment: I'll also add something I was just recently reminded about: running a set of N parallel FETs will reduce on-resistance to 1/N relative to just one... so arbitrarily low resistances are possible at the cost of higher leakage current and higher component count/cost

Comment: And one more question: where did you find this transistor at $0.05/1ku? On both Digikey and Mouser it's >$0.09/1ku

Comment: @MattThomas I'm not sure how the gate-to-source leakage current runs, I think you should read scientific papers about that. The name suggest from gate to source: then in shown circuit above, this leakage current in Q4 will run through and therefore contribute to the load. Moreover, I_GSS is defined with V_DS =0 which is *not* the case.

Comment: @MattThomas I don't see the benefit of using more mosfets in parallel. What voltage drop will 300 mohm give with 130uA?!  Moreover, the battery contacts and other components and maybe wiring will give you resistance too in the same order or even higher. So *halving* the R_DSON contributes maybe to a *quarter* less power losses.

Comment: I found the prices on the website of TI

Comment: So halving the R_DSON contributes maybe to a quarter less power losses. -> So halving the R_DSON contributes maybe to a (way) less *relative* power losses.